# Using iconv and file - how do I change an incorrect character encoding setting?

Tags: macos, character-encoding

I have a folder full of ASCII text files that have the file information set so text editors on the mac believe they are Turkish. The original notes in the folder claim it is Windows Latin 1 (Turkish is 5) so I believe the information on the file is simply incorrect. When I open the file on Windows, or in a browser on the Mac, it displays fine.

I learned that `file` reveals information about the type, so I tried that and got:

```
banka0.txt: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

When I try it on a file that does open property, I get:

```
ex3.nec: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

So where is this incorrect data, and how do I change it?

A little poking about online suggested `iconv` is the solution. However, this appears to convert the actual text inside the file, which I do not believe is the problem here, it's the metadata that's wrong. I tried it anyway, but no attempt to use it works:

```
iconv -t ascii < BANKA0 > BANKA0.ASCII
```

Which resulted in:

```
iconv: (stdin):1:0: cannot convert
```

I also tried UTF-8 and a number of others that all returned the same result.

UPDATE: some hex from the start of the file:

```
00000000  fe fe a1 39 01 00 13 58  3b 53 41 56 45 20 23 44  |...9...X;SAVE #D|
00000010  3a 42 41 4e 4b 41 30 e8  03 3d 06 41 b6 42 41 53  |:BANKA0..=.A.BAS|
00000020  49 43 20 58 4c 20 43 41  52 54 52 49 44 47 45 20  |IC XL CARTRIDGE |
00000030  20 28 43 29 20 31 39 38  34 20 4f 53 53 2c 20 49  | (C) 1984 OSS, I|
00000040  4e 43 2e 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 42 41  |NC.           BA|
00000050  4e 4b 31 41 f2 03 05 58  3b fc 03 28 58 3b 20 20  |NK1A...X;..(X;  |
00000060  20 20 20 20 20 50 52 45  41 44 59 20 2d 20 50 52  |     PREADY - PR|
00000070  49 4e 54 20 52 45 41 44  59 20 4d 45 53 53 41 47  |INT READY MESSAG|
00000080  45 06 04 05 58 3b 10 04  0a 86 50 52 45 41 44 59  |E...X;....PREADY|
00000090  1a 04 0b 24 3e 34 84 52  4d 53 47 24 04 0b 25 3e  |...$>4.RMSG$..%>|
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of one of those files, specifically a hex dump (using `hexdump -C file.txt`, or `xxd file.txt`, or HxD on Windows)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such setting.

Generally, `file` does not "reveal" any external metadata – it only tries to *detect* file types and a few common text encodings. It does so by guessing (it comes with a large database of distinguishing features), and some encodings (e.g. UTF-8 and US-ASCII) have distinct features that can be detected reliably, but many others appear identical to the computer.

For example, all ISO-8859-x charsets look pretty much alike – they're all single-byte encodings that use the same byte ranges, only map them to different characters. If you had a file in ISO-8859-9 (aka Latin-5) containing Turkish text, the `file` tool would still think it's ISO-8859-1 (aka Latin-1), and indeed any program would be able to *decode* it as ISO-8859-1 – the letters would be wrong, sure, but the decoder would have no way of knowing that.

The same applies to Windows-125x charsets, IBM charsets, and most likely MacOS codepages as well.

So in short, there's no file attribute that could be set (at least not one that would be understood by Windows and macOS alike) that says "this .txt file uses Latin-5". Just like the `file` tool, your text editors try to guess the correct encoding – typically on Windows they try UTF-8 first, and then fall back to whatever encoding is appropriate for the current Windows "Regional Settings".

(The `chardetect` tool can do more in-depth frequency analysis, but even then it is not able to fully distinguish certain codepages, e.g. even a large sample of ISO-8859-9 text still looks like "ISO-8859-1 with confidence 0.72" to this tool.)

Also, nearly these charsets are strict supersets of ASCII, which on its own can only represent the English/Latin alphabet. It does not make much sense to convert your file to ASCII – this would mean *throwing away* all the incorrect characters as none of them can be represented in plain ASCII. Usually you want to go in the other direction and convert the file to the *most* capable character set – typically Unicode using the `utf8` encoding.

So if you believe the text files are in Latin-5 (ISO-8859-9), tell iconv to convert *from* that to UTF-8:

```
iconv -f iso8859-9 -t utf8 < BANKA0 > BANKA0.NEW
```

MacOS, however, might have used a different codepage – "MacTurkish" or "IBM1281" (which I cannot find in GNU iconv, but it might be supported on macOS itself).

(Other file types, such as HTML, support embedded metadata and could have their charset specified *within* the file itself – but .txt files don't have an agreed-upon embedded metadata format, the whole file is just text.)

Comment: Ok so then the issue I was having was that you need to add the "from" type, I thought it might guess if not supplied and I did not know what to put there. The issue now is that it is **not** in Turkish, so the iconv turns it from one sort of gibberish to another. I tried several different "from" formats but they all had the same result. The file is from a 1980s computer in the US and should be pure ASCII.

Comment: Well, if it were ASCII, then it would be recognized by any text editor regardless of its encoding settings, because nearly all these charsets are *exact* ASCII supersets (the first 128 bytes have the exact same meaning in ISO-8859 or UTF-8 as they do in ASCII). But your hex dump shows byte values above 127, e.g. 0xFE at the very beginning – *that's outside ASCII range,* so by definition not "pure ASCII".

Comment: Actually it doesn't look like *text* in any encoding, it looks more like a binary / record-based format that has some ASCII text *in* it, e.g. computers like C64 would have stored BASIC programs in a binary "tokenized" format, with each byte representing a whole keyword...